# Dynamic Sheet name in Excel as DATE

Tags: excel

i found a code on the internet and tried it out. The code works. but my concern is that i wish to rename the sheet as Date. or at least allow the code to read the format mm/dd/yyyy from the cell.

here is the sample of the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set Target = Range("A1")
    If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ActiveSheet.Name = VBA.Left(Target, 31)
End Sub
```

if the value of A1 is 06/01/2016, i would like to have my sheet name as Jun01,2016 or at least have the name as Date.

Note.. i also tried other suggestion(s) from other sites but still not working

Answer (score 2):

We might need to tweak this if the date is stored as text.  Let me know.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If IsDate(Range("A1")) Then

        ActiveSheet.Name = Format(Range("A1"), "MM-DD-YYYY hh-mm-ss")

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Inzina.. This is the answer im looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure why this has to be a [Worksheet_SelectionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194470.aspx) event macro or why you are rewriting the Target parameter but perhaps this will work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target as Range)
    If Target.Address <> "$A$1" or Not IsDate(Range("A1")) Then Exit Sub
    Me.Name = Format(Target.Value2, "mmmdd,yyyy")
End Sub
```

Select A1 (and *just* A1) with a date (possibly `=today()`) in A1 and the worksheet's name will be adjusted (e.g. `Jul07,2016`).

Comment: Hi @Jeeped.. thanks for the answer.. unfortunately, when i used your code, the sheet name did not change its name at all.(used the value of A1)

Comment: Did you put it in a module code sheet or did you right click the worksheet's name tab and choose View Code to get to the worksheet's code sheet? Is the date in A1 right-aligned or left-aligned? Is it a true date or just text-that-looks-like-a-date?

Comment: view code, dont know if right or left aligned. true date

Comment: ... and you actually selected A1 and only A1?

Comment: actually what i need was from sheet 1 all through sheet 7 the date would increment. got my ans from @thomas.. had to create code per sheet but it works

Comment: Do a search for Workbook_SheetSelectionChange.